# comparing Big Decimal Value

Tags: java

I have a `BigDecimal` object, which I am checking for its value (greater or smaller than 100).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    BigDecimal obj = new BigDecimal("100.3");   
    if (obj.intValue() > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("Greater than 100");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not greater than 100");
    }   
}
```

But it's showing:

> Not greater than 100

Comment: `Why are you writing your text in code tags`?

Comment: `new BigDecimal("100.3").intValue()` is `100`. And 100 is not greater than 100

Comment: 100.3 as int is 100 that is not greater than 100

Answer (score 1):

The reason your logic fails is that `new BigDecimal("100.3").intValue()` will (as the method name suggests) give you the value without decimal precision, i.e. 100. And `100 > 100` will be false.

Instead, use `compareTo()` method of `BigDecimal` to compare

```
BigDecimal oneHundred = new BigDecimal("100");
BigDecimal obj = new BigDecimal("100.3");
if (obj.compareTo(oneHundred) > 0) {
    System.out.println("Greader than");
}
```